# Make a generic deserializer with protocol buffer

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers

I am working with RabbitMQ and protocol buffer on C# and C++. I have 5 different classes, each class will contain a field 'ActionType'. Depending on the number of the action type I want to call the right function, but when i getting the message from RabbitMQ I don't know to which class the message belongs to when I want to deserialize the message. Is there any way to deserialize/convert the message to an generic object, or maybe I can get only the value from the action type and then deserialize the message?

Comment: Can you have a base class with the ActionType field only? Deserialize into that one first and repeat with the proper class when you know the actual value of it.

Comment: @PepitoSh Thank you, i got it!

Answer (score 1):

In protobuf terms, this sounds like a `oneof` scenario, with 5 sub-messages. The `oneof` will give you a discriminator enum, and 5 messages. Meaning:

```
message OuterMesage {
    oneof actionType {
        Foo foo = 1;
        Bar bar = 2;
        ...
    }
}
message Foo {...}
message Bar {...}
...
```

You deserialize the data as an `OuterMesage`, and check via `.actionTypeCase` (typically in a `switch`) which of `.foo` / `.bar` etc to look at.

---

Note that if you're using protobuf-net this exact same scenario can also be modelled into inheritance, allowing polymorphism to be used; i.e.

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Foo)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Bar)]
public class OuterMessage { ... }

[ProtoContract]
public class Foo : OuterMessage {}

[ProtoContract]
public class Bar : OuterMessage {}
```

This is actually the *exact same data layout*, except now the message you get back from deserializing `OuterMessage` will be a `Foo`, a `Bar`, etc - as appropriate. So if you have a `virtual` (or `abstract`) method on `OuterMessage`, you can use polymorhiphism to invoke the appropriate one:

```
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<OuterMessage>(data); // obj could be Foo/Bar/etc
obj.DoTheThing(); // your virtual method
```